# How does autologging work in MLOps platforms like Comet or MLFlow?

Tags: comet, mlflow, mlops

I was wondering how the implementation of logging is done where you just need to create an experiment object from comet_ml and it auto-detects and gives out all the statistics of the trained experiment. Is there some sort of logging system used?

Answer (score 0):

Comet ML is not a supported MLflow flavor. You need to write your own custom flavor for it.

- https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/models.html#built-in-model-flavors
- https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/models.html#custom-flavors